# How could a Terminator ride a vehicle that was made to support the weight of a human?

Tags: the-terminator-series

In *[Terminator Judgement Day (1991)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103064/)* (T2) there is a scene of where Arnold is riding the motorcycle to follow John Connor, who is being chased by Robert Patrick (T1000). When Arnold jumps off the ledge with the motorcycle and lands, why do the tires not pop? Why do all the vehicles that exist within the series not break down when a terminator is riding them and/or maneuvering them?

The reasoning of why I ask the above is based on the fact that these Terminators like Arnold's  T-800 model must at least weigh in at a ton, if not more. I am sure the T-1000 and T-x also weigh a lot as well. So how can these vehicles that exist in the past be able to support them when a Terminator weighs way more than a human body frame or a vehicle that was made to support human weight?

Comment: Can we necessarily assume that they weigh a ton? They might be made of strong lightweight composites/alloys (polyalloy in the movie's parlance)

Comment: Arnold's [Endoskeleton](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Endoskeleton) was supposed to be made of a titanium alloy, which would not weigh that much.

Comment: I agree with @DVK.  Can you produce any info to base your assumption that they weigh that much?

Comment: Omg, some movie med guy said "this guy weights a ton", and everyone of you guys have marked "t-800 weight = 1 t" in your terminator memos?
I doubt that anyone of you can feel a difference between quarter ton and half ton weight, so med guy from T3 can't do it just like you.
T-800 is pretty massive thing for sure, but it's not solid metal statue, so it have a reasonable weight compared to human with same physique stats, about 200-250 kg. This makes possible for termo to use big bikes and all the cars.

Answer (score 27):

The terminators were designed for infiltration - to be able to sneak inside human enclaves and then terminate the people inside.

If a terminator weighed much more than a human of the same size/build, it would be a dead giveaway - and really easy for the resistance to spot.

Therefore, it seems reasonable to me that the terminators all weighed approximately the same as people.

Comment: No more than a human? Then why couldn't the burley Fireman lift the T-850 (Arnie) from the wreckage at the Veterinarian's office when he helped John Connor and Kate Brewster escape the T-X "Terminatrix" in 'T3 Rise of the Machines'?

Comment: @Morgan It's possible that it's just a limitation with the oldest Terminators. In the original, Kyle says that "these are new, they look human" and later models are smaller. The 800/850 distinction is dubious as it seems to have come exclusively from a T3 bonus feature.

Comment: The [T-850](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Series_850) is a T-800 with plasma-resistant skeleton, better joints and servos, better skin, and updated human psychology and behavior data. It also uses hydrogen fuel cells instead of the compact nuclear-energy Iridium cell used by the T-800.

Comment: Well the weight was also shown through the first part of Terminator 2 Judgement day. If the Terminator had human weight, there would be no way it would be able to bust through a wall of bricks. Essentially an object has to have a good amount of weight, unless it is thrown at a faster velocity, to break through a brick wall, as shown in the mall scene.

Comment: I'm not sure if "The Sarah Connor Chronicles" counts as part of the Terminator universe proper, but in one of the S2 episodes a terminator falls into the sea. It sinks to the bottom and has to walk ashore. That shows significantly higher density than a human.

Comment: @Mr.Boy Density is not tied to weight, as you likely realize.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 Density is _defined_ as mass/volume. So if a terminator is the same size (volume) as a man, but has higher density, it's mass _is_ greater. That a terminator doesn't float and a person does _proves_ the terminator is heavier than a person.

Comment: @mrboy That assumes that the Terminator has the same body composition as an adult male, which I don't think we can rrasonably assume. In this case I don't think density (the fact that the terminator doesn't float) is tied to its overall weight. We know that its skeleton is heavier and more dense than a human equivalent. That does not mean that it mist be heavier than a human.

Comment: It's worth noting that fat people float better than muscular people, and, well, the terminator has a lot of muscles. It's also worth noting it doesn't contain a lot of air (IE in lungs) or gases (EG flatulence). It might weigh the same, but it contains less gas overall. You also need to swim in order to maintain a floating position, and it looks like the terminator wasn't programmed for pool parties.

Comment: Well, you actually can float without swimming, but I think the point about the internal gasses and such makes sense.  In any case, this answerer's point is that a normal adult human can weigh a pretty wide range. Even for my own height of 6'1", I've weighed anything from 175lbs to nearly 270, based on my muscle and fat composition. And I've seen guys not much bigger than me add 100+lbs on top of that. The point is that a term could be heavier than a normal human of the same body volume without being so heavy that it raises alarm or breaks motorcycles.

Answer (score 15):

[Josh Friedman](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0295264/) said this during [a chat with fans](http://www.savethescc.com/transcribing-the-awesome/):

> 2:40AM – < ashman01> tantalum is actually very light, like titanium
>
> 2:40AM – < schmacky> LUcas@ T3 was stupid for making Terms so heavy..
>   how could they ever drive the cars if they were that heavy??
>
> 2:40AM – < ashman01> or just put a f&^**g scale outside of every
>   resistance base
>
> 2:40AM – <~astropixie> So they just suck at swimming, then?
>
> 2:40AM – < talli> @ash Didn’t Josh once say Cam weighs about 30% than
>   a human girl her size?
>
> 2:40AM – < ashman01> “john does my a$$ look fat?”
>
> 2:41AM – < jfhenry> **terminators weight hte same as human counterparts**

Comment: Who is Josh Friedman and why is his comment so valuable?

Comment: @Arvin Follow the link on the name. He is producer and writer of *Terminator:TSCC*...

Comment: Density of titanium = 4.51 g/cm^3.  Density of tantalum = 16.6 g/cm^3.  So much for learning science from a TV showrunner.

Answer (score 3):

It's a writing inconsistency. The only time I'm aware of where a Terminator's weight has been directly addressed in the movies is after the fight at Emery Animal Hospital in T3 between the T-850 and T-X. Here's a tongue-in-cheek running commentary of the T-850s weight discrepancy between movies.

> While the T-850 fires at the T-X ineffectively, the right arm of the T-X undergoes a painfully slow transformation into its most powerful weapon--a plasma cannon capable of causing minor inconvenience to Terminators. Like the T-X, the T-850 doesn't have any basic dodge routines, so the T-X has no problems hitting the T-850 with the cannon. The impact sends the T-850 flying all the way across the parking lot and into a building. The shot also causes the sort of cartoon-styled electrical interference that acts like a temporary x-ray.
>
> The T-850 is temporarily stunned, so the T-X converts the cannon back into a normal arm.
> As John Connor flees, emergency responders are seen travelling the opposite direction. They arrive at the scene of the explosion, and EMT's quickly locate the T-850. Discovering that the T-850 has no pulse, one of the EMT's attempts to move the T-850 while the other stands there doing nothing. The EMT is unable to move the T-850, because "this guy weighs a ton". Of course. Terminators need to blend in with humans, so naturally they should be built so heavy that they can shatter asphalt and concrete on impact, and react like a stone statue when manipulated by humans. Contrast this with T2, where a 10-year-old boy was able to help a Terminator to its feet.
> http://downfallofterminator.blogspot.com/2013/04/all-that-is-wrong-with-terminator-3.html

Comment: In T2, the extent of John's help is giving him an order to get up.

Comment: @Mazura - No, he basically picks him up.  https://youtu.be/pYj8CUA9FZc?t=3m3s